# VueFire object undefined

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuefire

I have the following:

```
const firebase = {
  items: {
    source: db.ref('items'),
    asObject: true,
    readyCallback: function() {
      console.log('items retrieved!');
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  firebase,
  render: (h) => h(App)
});
```

If I look in the console of the browser, I get to see 'items retrieved!' after a few seconds, but when I write

`{{ typeof items }}`

in the template I get undefined. I followed the docs on the VueFire Github page but can't seem to get it working.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thx

Comment: *Where* are you adding `{{typeof items}}`? In App.vue? If so, then your error is expected. The `firebase` reference is defined in the *root* Vue, not in App.vue.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to access properties from the Vue instance, use the function syntax, You have to use firebase as a function

```
const firebase = function(){
    return {
        items: {
            source: db.ref('items'),
            asObject: true,
            readyCallback: function() {
                console.log('items retrieved!');
            }
       }
    }
}

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    firebase,
    render: (h) => h(App)
});
```